# Find month number from user input using list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program where the user enters the month number and it will display e.g. September has 30 days. The program must find a number of days from the list.

```
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
```

I have tried the following code so far and I know the `days[counter]` is taking 31,28,31... which can't match with user input. I also used `for counter in range(len(days))` but couldn't get the possible solution.

```
def getValidMonth():
  userInput = 0
  while userInput < 1 or userInput > 12:
    userInput = int(input("Please enter the valid number of month: "))
  return userInput

def findDays(userInput):
  days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  for counter in range(1,13):
    if days[counter] == userInput:
      print("Jan has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("Feb has 28 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("Mar has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("April has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("May has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("June has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("July has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("August has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("September has 30 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("October has 31 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("November has 30 days")
    elif days[counter] == userInput:
      print("December has 31 days")
  
def main():
  userInput = getValidMonth()
  findDays(userInput)

main()
```

I know there is a solution by importing `datetime` and `calendar` but I am trying to do with the list. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: `if days[counter] == userInput` is incorrect logic. If the user enters "4", you are basically checking if any value in your list `days` is "4". Which is never True.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def findDays(userInput):
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    return f"{months[userInput-1]} has {days[userInput-1]} days."

>>> findDays(4)
'Apr has 30 days.'
```

###### Explanation:

If the user enters "1", you are returning the element at the 0th (`userInput-1`) index

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using a dictionary:

```
MONTHS = {
    1: ("Jan", 31),
    2: ("Feb", 28),
    ...
}
```

and then using the user input:

```
def findDays(userInput):
    print(f"{MONTHS[userInput][0]} has {MONTHS[userInput][1]} days.")
```

Usually using consecutive integers as dictionary keys gives us a hint to use an array, but this might require to manipulate the indices, and a dictionary doesn't need this kind of manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which will work which handles the invalid input as well:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

def find_days(month_no):
    try:
        if int(month_no) < 1 or int(month_no) > 12:
            return "Month No. should be in the range 1 to 12"
            
        return months[int(month_no)-1]+ " has " + str(days[int(month_no)-1])+" days"
    except ValueError as ex:
        return "Input should be integer number"
    
month = input()
print (find_days(month))
```